# How should I design my application flow for working with google doc files?

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an application which is supposed to automatically fill placeholders of one google doc file and clone the result into the user's drive. Once I upload the doc file into developer's drive and when logged-in user requests resolved doc file, the following processes occur:

1. Gather information related to the user from remote services.
2. Get google doc file from developer's drive.
3. Parse placeholder from google doc file and replace them with gathered info.
4. Save resulting file as json into the database.
5. Upload resulting file into the user's drive.
6. As soon as file is uploaded - share link with user. Also give user the ability to download generated file as .docx.

The question is if it's possible to implement all steps using Java Google Docs API? Also I am not sure if the step with downloading file as .docx possible to implement?

Comment: Take a look at this, Google provides various REST API which can satisfy all the features you mentioned : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Comment: You can acheive all the features you mentioned, by any simple web application, which communicates with API, send results to backend, takes response, and show result to user

Comment: You are right, but I cannot find the feature in google drive api which allows me to upload single file to the developer drive manually. I need to upload it not from code but from developer console, is it possible to do? Also didn't find library for converting google doc to docx file.